# Yii2: Path issue while redirecting with pretty url from login

Tags: yii2

i have enabled pretty url in url manager & tried login with. When logs in successfully to my dashboard, i am getting problem w.r.t CSS & JS loading for that page as the path makes problem i have analyzed the problem in network problem the screen shots are below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

First screen shot is the image when i am trying login without enabling pretty UR...works fine
How to fix this issue.

Second:This is the login page when i enabled pretty url & opened login view

Third: This is the third image when i logs in where the path issue occurs. the path to load css & JS differs & hence i am getting 404 error in network panel

Comment: How are you including your CSS and JS files?

Comment: $this->registerJsFile('js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js');

Comment: i am adding through this way in the view

Comment: why not using a assetBundle for this?

Comment: do you mean AppAsset.php???

Comment: For sure he mean that

Comment: Show us your urlManager config

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        ],

Comment: well i was using asset bundle still i was not working so i switched to registering locally the CSS & JS files in the view itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really have much to do with the fact that your urlManager is enabled, but rather how you are registering your assets.

You could just add the js and css files to your Asset Bundle e.g. `/frontend/assets/AppAssets.php` and make sure that your bundle is published in the layout file e.g. `/frontend/views/layout/main.php` view.

You could also just try:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js');
```

Instead of

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js');
```

which looks for the file relative to the url, that's why it's not working with the urlManager enabled.

Comment: well even this doesnot work...for now i have stopped using yii2 as am frustrated a little on these silly issues. i am developing my project in core-php.

Comment: This is the right answer. @Shaggie you are lacking basic understanding of how paths work. No framework will help you. Some might do what you want but that is just covering a lack of knowledge.